# Can the localized price be determined?

Tags: android-pay

In google wallet I set the price in USD - but I am selling digital goods, my customer might be anywhere in the world

Is there some way to see what Google Wallet will charge in a localized currency?

Answer (score 0):

Typically StackOverflow is for technical questions.  But what the heck, I'll take a crack at this one.

Google Wallet doesn't convert your price in USD to the customer's native currency.  It does the opposite, so the price of your good is fixed and the amount that you'll receive is variable depending on the current forex rate.  You should IP geolocate and define the market price of the item in the geolocated currency.